# How to install JDK5 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, jdk

I have installed 11.04 in my machine. I have installed JDK6 from the repository. My problem is I need to install JDK5 in my machine I have used the following command but its not working.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
```

It gives the following messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sun-java5-jdk
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually download it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html  and then install it.

Comment: As a java developer I can confirm that a manual install is the best option for java. Just make sure that you set your paths correctly: `export JAVA_HOME=/data/dev/java/java6 - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`. Pretty easy to switch between different java versions and JDKs that way.

Comment: Can you also give the instructions for installing it once the .bin file is downloaded. Oracle does not have any instructions. Thanks in advance.